# How to change my code to work a certain number of times?

Tags: vb.net, list, random

My code gets a list of words from a txt file and chooses the words randomly. However, the same word can appear more than once and i need to know how to stop this from happening?

Here is the code:

```
Dim aryName As String() = Nothing
aryName = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\Random\fnames.txt")

Dim randomWords As New List(Of String)
For i = 0 To aryName.Length - 1
If randomWords.Contains(aryName(i)) = False Then
    randomWords.Add(aryName(i))
End If
Next

Dim random As New Random
Label2.Text = (randomWords(random.Next(0, randomWords.Count - 1)).ToString)
```

Maybe  this might work, although it's in english and not code :(

```
if label1.text is changed then
  Get label1.text
  if label.text becomes this word again then
    run the random code
  end if
end if
```

Comment: Do you mean that there are duplicates in the input list or that the same word is being chosen multiple times?

Comment: So, random words are appearing in aryName multiple times?

Comment: Do you want a shuffle method?

Comment: @ChrisF no there are not duplicates in the list but yes the same word is being chosen multiple times

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 yes they are

Comment: @Cobold it would be appreciated if you told me what this method is and give an example

Answer (score 1):

This should prevent immediate repeats:

```
Dim random As New Random

'Just create a temporary holder for comparison
Dim word As String = Label2.Text

'Run a while loop that works as long as there
'is no change to the word. This should prevent
'back to back repeats.
While word = Label2.Text
    word = (randomWords(random.Next(0, randomWords.Count - 1)).ToString)
End While

Label2.Text = word
```

If you don't want it to repeat ever again, you should probably remove the used word from the randomWords List.

```
Dim random As New Random
Label2.Text = (randomWords(random.Next(0, randomWords.Count - 1)).ToString)
randomWords.Remove(Label2.Text)
```

Comment: @user1081679: I would expect you to treat this more like pseudo-code. It may need slight modification based on how your code actually operates. Which one doesn't do what you want it to do, and what exactly are you wanting it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can a) remove the selected word from the list, or b) you can random sort the list first.
Option a) is already addressed in another answer
Option b) lets you retain all the words in memory. Here is the code:

```
    Dim randomWords As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\Random\fnames.txt"))

    Dim random As New Random

    randomWords.Sort(Function(s1 As String, s2 As String) random.Next(-1, 1))

    For index As Integer = 0 To randomWords.Count - 1
        Label2.Text = randomWords(index)
    Next
```

Comment: You need to store all the random words into the Form, as well as the index of the last word used. When a new word is requested increment the index and pull the word from the list. The reading from the file should occur once. I know this works, because I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your For loop to prevent dupes in aryName from getting into randomWords:

```
For i = 0 To aryName.Length - 1
    If randomWords.Contains(aryName(i)) = False Then
        randomWords.Add(aryName(i))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Does it throw an error of some kind?  Basically all this does is check to see if the array value already exists in randomWords, and only adds it if it does not exist.